# what is the proper way to make a list of gtkwidgets

Tags: gtk

I have some difficulties to make a list of customized GtkWidgets.

My customized widget encompase a GtkImage and a GtkLabel.

To make a list of widget I use a gtkbox packed in a GtkScrolledWindow, my GtkBox (a vertical box ) is used to pack all of my customized widgets
but what I obtain is not good. when scrolling, the entire surface is redrawn
and some flicker appears which is not good.

So I want to know if it exists another way to this job in a good way.
With Qt it is possible so I hope that in Gtk it is possible too.

Thanks

Comment: I have some requirements too like getting click event from my customized widgets to do some specific jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Making a list out of a scrolling GtkVBox is a fairly common way to do it. You could make a custom GtkVBox subclass that only showed the widgets which are on screen, hiding the rest of them.

You might want to check and see if the [EggListBox](http://git.gnome.org/browse/egg-list-box/tree/) widget does what you need (license permitting obviously). It is a GtkContainer that can handle scrolling and you just need to add the widgets with `gtk_container_add`

Comment: a gtkscrolledwindow can do that with a GtkVBox add to it with gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport() but the problem is the same because some flicker apperas because each visible widget has to be drawn when we scroll the scrollbar. an on screen drawing seems to be a good solution the use of a snapshot too I suppose

Comment: You missed the point I was trying to make, if you make a custom GtkBox then you can get away with not drawing the widgets that are offscreen.Using _add_with_viewport means the GtkBox still has to draw them even if they're offscreen, which causes the flicker.

Comment: How to know that a particular widget is in an offscreen state? I don't see any thing about that in GtkWidget signals

Comment: You would need to keep track of the position of the list and when the list has moved work out what widget is offscreen by looking at it's coordinates

Comment: hellok there is no changes, I have made a custom class_container->forall function which only look for Gtkwidget in the drawing portion of the viewport but, the problem remains the same. I suppode that the scrolling bar change its value very fast and that is the problem.

Comment: gtkcellrender seems to be a good solution with a custom cell render